# Google maps doesn't load in Cordova app on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, google-maps

I'm building hybrid app with Cordova. In my app there must be Google Maps. For some reason Google Maps opening in browsers but when i run it on Android device, map isn't loading.

On network i get this :
[image: App network via chrome inspector]

In console: 
[image: App console via chrome inspector]

I use angular js so i used ng-map( same problem as now) and now i use angular-google-maps.

My html:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map class="googlemap"
                center="{ latitude: 54.722410, longitude: 25.331595 } "
                zoom="14"
                pan="false"
                options="options"
                >

            <ui-gmap-marker
                    idKey="1"
                    coords="{ latitude: 54.722410, longitude: 25.331595 }"
                    ></ui-gmap-marker>

        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

My angular controller:

```
angular.module('Framework')

.controller('MapController', function InfoController($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, Api, localStorageService) {

    $scope.info = localStorageService.get('info');

})
```

;

My configs:

```
angular.module('Framework', ['Framework.config',
'ngMaterial',
'nemLogging',
'ngCordova',
'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
'ngMdIcons',
'ITGMill',
'LocalStorageModule'
 ])
 .config(
    function appConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, ApiProvider, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider, LANGUAGES, API_URL) {

        uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            key: 'AIzaSyA0FGopQ_NUWZUh9lkkEBtR9oOYR-3t53c',
            //v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
        });
```

Comment: Check that the google maps domain is whitelisted in the config.xml file.

Comment: <access origin="*" /> i think this will do

Comment: It will do provided you have the whitelist plugin in your project.